# I am looking for any starter kit or boiler plate using laravel

Tags: laravel, boilerplate, react-starter-kit

I have just finished with prototype, and I am eagerly searching for any starter kit or boiler plate, I have searched but unable to get access if anyone knows any website or link it would be great.

Comment: You know Laravel comes with a React preset as well as the default Vue one?

Comment: What's wrong with [the default one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe some one of the following?

#### Admin panel

- https://backpackforlaravel.com/
- https://laravelvoyager.com/

#### Laravel + Vue + Tailwind

- https://github.com/adamwathan/laravel-preset

If not, checkout Awesome laravel, a list of hundreds of useful tools, packages and repos: https://github.com/chiraggude/awesome-laravel